# Cloning a computer upgraded from Windows Vista to 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, sysprep

We have quite a few laptops that came with licenses for Windows Vista. We have plenty of upgrade licenses to go from Vista to 7. However, I don't want to manually upgrade each laptop. If I install Vista, upgrade it to 7, and then sysprep and clone the laptop, can I still activate using the upgrade license? Or will it expect a full Windows 7 license key?

Comment: You can `sysprep /generalize` your "upgraded" Windows "image". Generalizing will reset the activation timer (to 30 days) after which you will need to enter the product key for Windows and re-active online. You _should_ be able to use your "upgrade" keys because you have, technically, had Vista previously and upgraded it...

Comment: Create an image while using the generic Windows 7 license key, sysprep the image, apply image.  Then create a script to change the license key and apply it manually to each machine

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean by generic Windows 7 license? Also, it's been my experience that you can't activate a clean install of Windows 7 with an Upgrade license.

Comment: There exists a generic license key for each version of Windows 7 designed around the purpose of creating an image, installing applications, then applying that image across machines.  This license cannot be activate, but an actual Windows 7 license, should have no problem being activated.

Comment: @Ramhound Gotcha. Do you mean these keys: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612867.aspx ? Those state that you must have a KMS server to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to Sysprep a system that has been upgraded to a newer OS version.

[image: Error Message]